# $f$ be an analytic function defined on $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $f$ be an analytic function defined on $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ such that the range of $f$ is contained in the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Then
>
> 1. $f$ is necessarily a constant function.
> 2. there exists an analytic function $g$ on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $g(x)$ is a square root of $f(z)$ for each $z\in\mathbb{D}$.
> 3. there exists an analytic function $g$ on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\operatorname{Re}g(z)\geq 0$ and $g(z)$ is a square root of $f(z)$ for each $z\in\mathbb{D}$.
> 4. there exists an analytic function $g$ on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\operatorname{Re}g(z)\leq 0$ and $g(z)$ is a square root of $f(z)$ for each $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

I have to determine which options are correct.
Can someone help in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Where did you come across it?  What have you tried?

Comment: [Identical question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293781/if-f-is-an-analytic-function-on-the-unit-disk-whose-range-is-contained-in-ma) (including same wording at beginning and end) was posted Feb 3 and deleted Feb 4 by [user33640](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/52976/user33640).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option $2,3,4 $ are true, Hint: In a simply connected domain,  $f\neq 0$ and analytic, then it is possible to define single valued analytic branches of $\,\,\log f(z)$ and $\displaystyle (f(z))^{\frac{1}{n}}$