# $f$ is analytic function over a unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f$ be an analytic  function on a unit disk $D=\left \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1 \right \}$  such that the range of the function is contained in the $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty,0]$.  Then i have to prove that .

> There exist an analytic function $g$ on $D$ such that $g(z)$ is a square root of $f(z)$ for all $z \in D$

I tried my best but not getting even close to this question's approch .How can i find a function which is analytic and range of which function is $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty,0]$ .  I think A bilinear transformation can help me because by using that i can map a disk over a disk in .[$f$ be an analytic function defined on $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297741/f-be-an-analytic-function-defined-on-mathbbd-z-in-mathbbcz1) .The solution is provide here but this solution is talking about analytic branches i Have no idea about them .Please Help.

Comment: F or this you need the fact that there is an analytic function $h$ on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ such that $e^{h(z)}=z$ for all $z$. Once you kn ow this you can take $g(z)=e^{1/2 h(f(z))}$.

Comment: In particular note that the shape of $D$ is completely irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $g(z)=\exp\left(\frac{\log f(z)}2\right)$, where $\log$ is an analytic branch of the logarithm defined on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: You mean $f(z)$, not $z$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.